# wp8 winrt pcl could not deploy app on device when mvvm light framework is implemented

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I have a solution with a pcl, winrt and wp8 project.
I want to share the models and implement mvvm light framework.
It works fine, I can see the binding property in the xaml design mode, but when I deploy the app to device I get the following exception: *The network connection to 127.0.0.1:8016 has been lost. Debugging will be aborted.*

So when I remove the following line for initialisation the locator I can deploy, but mvvm is not implemented!

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator p6:Key="Locator" p7:IsDataSource="True" xmlns:p7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" xmlns:p6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" />
```

Has anybody an idea what is up there?

bye
Markus

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a simpler sintax

```
<vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MultiPlatform.WP8.UI.ViewModels"
                           x:Key="Locator" />
```

more info at https://github.com/cmorgado/MultiPlatform